# Перезапуск фрагмента из RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, fragment-back-stack, fragment-manager, fragment-transaction

Разрабатываю приложение несколько месяцев, оно постепенно обрастает новыми добавлениями. Вкратце - это интернет магазин, оформлен в виде одной активити с `NavigationDrawer`, все страницы реализованы на фрагментах, в некоторых случаях в дело вступает backstack, например в случае каталога, у которого есть 4 уровня вложенности - основные категории, подкатегории, список продуктов, страница продукта. первые два оформлены в виде `ListView`, третий в виде `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`.

Метод `onBackPressed` в активити определен следующим образом

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    ProductPageFragment ppf = (ProductPageFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Flags.Stack.PRODUCT_PAGE_FRAGMENT);
    Log.d("ppf", ppf + "");
    SubcatalogFragment sf = (SubcatalogFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Flags.Stack.SUBCATALOG_FRAGMENT);
    Log.d("sf", sf + "");
    ProductGridFragment pf  = (ProductGridFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Flags.Stack.PRODUCT_GRID_FRAGMENT);
    Log.d("pf", pf + "");
    CartMainFragment cmf = (CartMainFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Flags.Stack.CART_FRAGMENT);
    Log.d("cmf", cmf + "");
    PurchaseFragment purf = (PurchaseFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Flags.Stack.PURCHASE_FRAGMENT);
    Log.d("purf", purf + "");

    boolean sfVisible = sf != null && sf.isVisible();
    boolean ppfVisible = ppf != null && ppf.isVisible();
    boolean pfVisible = pf != null && pf.isVisible();
    boolean cmfVisible = cmf != null && cmf.isVisible();
    boolean purfVisible = purf != null && purf.isVisible();


    //If the fragment exists and has some back-stack entry
    if ((sfVisible || pfVisible || ppfVisible || cmfVisible || purfVisible) && getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        bpCount = 0;
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

    //Else, nothing in the direct fragment back stack
    else {
        // Let super handle the back press
        bpCount++;
        switch (bpCount) {
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Для выхода нажмите \"Назад\" ещё раз",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                super.onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`bpCount`, в данном случае, – счетчик нажатий на *back*, чтобы приложение не закрывалось по первому нажатию.

На главной странице потребовалось разместить популярные продукты, использовал для этого `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager` и тем же `viewholder`, что и в списке продуктов. По нажатию на итем должна открываться страница продукта. Запускаем приложение - видим список продуктов, открываем страницу первого попавшегося продукта - отрисовывается нормально. Нажимаем клавишу back, видим главную, открываем другой продукт (или этот же, не имеет значения) и фрагмент не отрисовывается. если помещать его в контейнер методом replace - то видим серый экран (стандартный фон) на месте контейнера, если add, то RecyclerView отскролливается на выбранный продукт, при этом в обоих случаях onCreateView фрагмета выполняется.

Код, вызывающий фрагмент выглядит так:

```
private void showProductPage() {
    ProductPageFragment ppf = new ProductPageFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(PRODUCT_TAG, product);

    ppf.setArguments(bundle);

    ((Activity) this.itemView.getContext()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ppf, Flags.Stack.PRODUCT_PAGE_FRAGMENT)
            .addToBackStack(Flags.Stack.CATALOG_BACKSTACK)
            .commit();
}
```

`this` - это `viewholder`, `itemView` - view холдера, контекст является инстансом активити.

Мне бы хотелось понять, почему такое может происходить, ведь по первому клику фрагмент отрисовывается нормально. И если кто нибудь подробно может мне объяснить разницу между основными методами `FragmentTransaction`, то я тоже был бы очень признателен. Спасибо.

PS. Да, забыл, к чему я, собственно, расписывал как устроен каталог - во всем каталоге нажатие на back отрабатывает нормально, а вот со страницей продукта происходит такая же ерунда, как и при открытии его с главной. При первом запуске страница продукта отрисовывается, а потом - нет.

PPS. Удалил лишние проверки из popBackStack, на всякий случай, ситуация не изменилась. Вроде всё выполняется в одном потоке, но объявлял syncronized как метод, так и блок, результат тот же. Мне не понятно, почему метод onCreateView выполняется, как и остальные методы фрагмента, в  методе onResume вывожу isVisible и оно true, но при этом вьющка не рисуется. Или может она рисуется где то ещё? Смотрим реализацию isVisible в базовом классе фрагмента:

```
    final public boolean isVisible() {
        return isAdded() && !isHidden() && mView != null
                && mView.getWindowToken() != null && mView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }
```

Значит нам надо выяснить, как реализованы и что значат все эти условия. Ищем isAdded

```
    final public boolean isAdded() {
        return mActivity != null && mAdded; // Задается FragmentManager при добавлении фрагмента
    }
```

isHidden:

```
    final public boolean isHidden() {
        return mHidden; // значение задается функциями showFragment и hideFragment вызванные из экземляра FragmentManager
    }
```

mView это view фрагмента, который создаётся в onCreateView,

view.getWindowToken выглядит так

```
    public IBinder getWindowToken() {
        return mAttachInfo != null ? mAttachInfo.mWindowToken : null;
```

// возвращет null если view не присоединено к контейнеру
        }
ну и View.VISIBLE означает, что view фрагмента отрисовывается.

Следовательно ОС считает, что фрагмент у меня нарисован и существует.

Answer (score 4):

1. Не увидел в вашем коде используете ли вы рекомендованный паттерн [OnFragmentInteraction](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) - судя по обилию всяких условий в `onBackPressed` видимо нет, а зря. Смысл паттерна, в том, что корневой `Activity` должен реализовывать интерфейс отрабатывающий изменения в подчиненных фрагментах. Грубо говоря, если вы выбрали некий элемент списка, то корневой `Activity` должен быть в курсе этого, чтобы при возврате обратно отработать эти изменения.
2. По-моему это плохая идея ловить `onBackPressed` - гораздо удобнее работать с `onBackStackChanged` примерно так:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackStackChanged() {
       Log.i(TAG, "Back stack changed!");
       Log.i(TAG, "Stack size=" + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
       if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==0) {//we're on main
           //перерисовываем здесь
       }
       shouldDisplayHomeUp();
   }
   ```

Для перерисовки надо или дать знать фрагменту, что контент изменился - типа `notifyDatasetChanged` или просто перерисовать `Cursor` который лежит под фрагментом (если лежит).

Можно попробовать отцепить и заново прицепить фрагмент:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .detach(contentFragment)
            .attach(contentFragment)
            .commit();
```

Говорят работает - честно скажу не пробовал.

Comment: Прицепить и отцепить не пробовал и не буду без надобности. По поводу паттерна - большое спасибо, изучить это дейстительно стоит. Решил проблему, уйдя от стандартной либы к саппорт-в4, которая по всей видимости стабильнее.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в адаптер передать ссылку на фрагмент, коий содержит ваш `RecyclerView` и вместо `FragmentManager`-а активити использовать `FragmentManager` фрагмента, который можно получить методом `getChildFragmentManager()` класса `Fragment`.

Т.е. вместо

> ((Activity) this.itemView.getContext()).getFragmentManager()

сделать

```
 instanceOfYoursFragmentThatHoldesRecycleViewWhichYouPassToAdaptersClass.getChildFragmentManager()
```

Comment: Но ведь контейнер находится в разметке активити. Если я буду использовать `getChildFragmentManager`, то поиск `R.id.container` будет производиться по разметке фрагмента.

Comment: В любом случае - не получилось, как я и предсказывал. Схватил ошибку на попытке найти контейнер для фрагмента. У меня есть подозрение, что старый фрагмент не успевает умереть, перед созданием нового, и на взаимном воздействии они глючат. Но это предположение, может и не верное.